# New Yahoo Mail interface unread messages not shown in bold

Tags: yahoo-mail

As you may have noticed Yahoo Mail's new interface is now a lot like Gmail. I like it, however the unread messages is not showing in bold font.

[image]

There doesn't seem to be an option to change this in the settings. I am using latest Firefox, Windows 7 BTW.

My question is: How can I make it bold?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Unless you do something like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/better-gmail-2/ and modify it to support `Yahoo Mail` you are at the mercy of Yahoo. If there is no setting to change this option you are out of luck.

Comment: You can possibly try IE and force it to use Compatibility mode or IE7 mode. This can sometimes trip up a website to think you are using an old browser and in turn will render the page with old code.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I get with Windows 7 IE 11 preview - zoom 125% 1600x900 resolution.

[image]

Try changing the theme using the icon on the bottom left. The bold looks more obvious on some. This is light grey.